# java formatter output incorrect

Tags: java, string, io, formatting

```
try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("metrics.csv");
                Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
                fmt.format(
                        "%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%3s", "",
                        "ANA", "NOM", "NOA", "ITC", "ETC", "CAC", "DIT",
                        "CLD", "NOC", "NOD", ",\n");
                for(int i = 0;i< class_list.getModel().getSize(); i++){
                    fmt.format(
                            "%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s%3s", declaration.getClassesName().get(i),
                            declaration.getANA(i), declaration.getNOM(i), declaration.getNOA(i), declaration.getITC(i), declaration.getETC(i), declaration.getCAC(i), declaration.getDIT(i),
                            declaration.getCLD(i), declaration.getNOC(i), declaration.getNOD(i), ",\n");
                }
                writer.append(fmt.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                System.out.println("done");
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
```

all get functions return a string which length is smaller than 10.
The output that i get is:

> ```
>              ANA       NOM       NOA       ITC       ETC       CAC       DIT       CLD       NOC       NOD ,
> Equipe     0.33
>      3         1         1         1         3         0         0         0         0 , 
> Participant      0.0
>      1         1         0         0         0         0         1         2         2 ,
> Joueur     0.33
>      3         3         0         1         1         1         0         0         0 , 
> Entraineur      0.0
>      1         2         0         0         1         1         0         0         0 ,
> Stade      2.0
>      1         2         1         0         1         0         0         0         0 ,
> ```

as you can see, the column is not aligned. Anyone knows where is the problem in my code?
Thanks.

---

edit 1:
here is my getANA function.

```
 public String getANA(){
    if (operations.size()==0) return "0";
    int arg_sum = 0;
    for(Operation o : operations){
        arg_sum+=o.getArgumentNumber();
    }
    return String.format("%.2g%n", (double)arg_sum/operations.size());
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `ANA` string has a newline on the end of it? Maybe try printing it out by itself or just `ANA` and `NOM` and see how it shows up.

Comment: most likely `ANA` has a `\r\n` at the end, especially if it is coming from a Windows machine.

Comment: @BinaryJudy you are right, its my getANA function's problem. But how do I fix it? It returns double with 2 decimals in string type.

Comment: you have never heard of the `.trim()` method?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I found the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking out the `%n` in your `getANA()` method:

```
return String.format("%.2g", (double)arg_sum/operations.size());
```